# Cannot install PC BSD

Tags: ubuntu, partition, freebsd, system-installation, dual-boot

Currently I am using Ubuntu. I wanted to try PC BSD so downloaded 10.2. On trying to install it on a separate primary partition(so that I can dual-boot) I am getting the following error.[image]

Do anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually an error associated with PC-BSD installer 10.2. Its actually fixed for version 11. https://forums.pcbsd.org/thread-20180.html

Answer (score 2):

The error was associated with an **August 2015** distribution of installers for PC-BSD 10.2.

The usual repository for 10.2 (with August 2015 content), linked from the [PC-BSD download](http://www.pcbsd.org/download/) page:

http://download.pcbsd.org/iso/10.2-RELEASE/amd64/

A topic in PC-BSD forums – [10.2 installer bug](https://forums.pcbsd.org/thread-20180.html) – drew attention to [Bug #11097: gpt + bios install not working with PC-BSD 10.1.2+ - PCBSD - Bug Tracking System](https://bugs.pcbsd.org/issues/11097) with fixes on 2015-09-06 and 2015-09-07 and:

> … re-roll the 10.2 ISO's to fix it soon, probably in the next couple of weeks. The fix should be in the 11.0-SEPT images though. …

– followed by confirmation that the installer for PC-BSD 11.0-CURRENT worked as expected.

Around six months later in the same topic, https://forums.pcbsd.org/thread-20180-post-113427.html#pid113427 drew attention to `PCBSD10.2-RELEASE-09-12-2015-x64-DVD-USB` (**September 2015**, a little later than both fixes), which is found in an *edge* repository:

http://download.pcbsd.org/iso/10.2-RELEASE/edge/amd64/